# Can the name parameter in SerializationInfo.AddValue() be arbitrary?

Tags: c#, serialization

I'm trying to serialize all the TreeNodes in a TreeView object.  The trouble is that if the nodes have the same name then it throws a SerializationException.

```
public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (TreeNode node in this.Nodes)
            {
                info.AddValue(node.FullPath, node);
            }
        }
catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex.Message == "Cannot add the same member twice to a SerializationInfo object.")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You cannot save more than one gallery with the same name.  Change the name(s) and try again.");
            }
        }
    }
```

When the objects are being added using AddValue() can I make the name arbitrary so that no conflicts occur?

Failing that, what would be a suggested solution?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the name can be 'arbitrary' - *but* names can *not* be duplicated within the same serialization info.

See [SerializationInfo.AddValue Method (String, Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/skf8dbad(v=vs.110).aspx).

> [Throws a] SerializationException [if] A value has already been associated with name.

and

> If two values are added with names that differ only by case, no exception will be thrown, which is not a recommended practice. However, *adding two values with the exact same name will cause the SerializationException to be thrown.*

This is because the SerializationInfo acts as a dictionary / associative array.

Comment: So `info.AddValue(node.FullPath + DateTime.Now.Ticks, node)` would work??

Comment: @PaulMatthews Probably not (because Ticks doesn't have that fine a resolution), but more so it violates the purpose of the name as an identifier - eg. when used with `GetValue` later.

Comment: What would your suggestion be?

Comment: Why not just add `AddValue("nodes", Nodes.ToArray())`?

Comment: Tried `TreeNode[] Nodes = new TreeNode[this.Nodes.Count]; 
this.Nodes.CopyTo(Nodes, 0);
info.AddValue("Nodes", Nodes);` but nodes are deserialized as 'null'

Comment: `info.AddValue(Convert.ToString(this.Nodes.IndexOf(node)), node)` seems to serialize and deserialize fine.  Is that a bad way to do it also?

Comment: It's better than the timestamp. Although I would urge trying to keep 'data' out of the name.